# Is mapping property names with dot is allowed in Elasticsearch Index Management?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, a JSON file with key-value pair where the key name has a dot in between it. When this file is uploaded, the dot is treated as next line \n and the name will split into two properties. I tried to use mapper.allow_dots_in_name=True in the setting but no effect.

Similar question posted by someone else, but no reply https://discuss.elastic.co/t/disable-expansion-of-field-names-with-dots-in-mapping/84761

Appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elasticsearch 2.4 includes a property where the field names can include a dot. And the field will not get converted to object style mapping.

This setting can be enabled by

> export ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Dmapper.allow_dots_in_name=true"

But from 5.x, it is not possible to get a field value with dots without converting it into object mapping. If you index a field like `abc.foo.bar` (with no explicit mapping). This will get converted to

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "abc": {
        "properties": {
          "foo": {
            "properties": {
              "bar": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**It is best to avoid dots in the field names. You can refer to this documentation, to know more about [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/dots-in-names.html#_upgrading_fields_with_dots_to_5_x)**